# JavaScript event onblur is firing before onfocus in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am getting a problem when using `onblur` and `onfocus` event of textbox in Firefox.

In Opera. it works as expected (e.g. `onfocus` is called first, then `onblur`).

In Firefox, `onblur` is called first, then it calls `onfocus`. This should not happen.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Suggest you edit your question to include your code here, or create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for people to quickly test your code.

Comment: In my opinion it makes sense for `onblur` to come before `onfocus`, otherwise focus is in two places at once. I believe both IE and FF do it this way. Why do you assume the Opera way is the "correct" way?

Comment: I agree with nnnnnn, Opera's behavior is the one that's wrong. You should better explain why the order of events matters for you - you might get a suggestion on how to fix your code then.

Answer (score 3):

It's good to know that some browsers are broken in this way. Consider the following code.

```
<input type="text" id="t1" onfocus="is_editing=true" onblur="is_editing=false" />
<input type="text" id="t2" onfocus="is_editing=true" onblur="is_editing=false" />
```

In Opera, if you click on either textfield, `is_editing` will be true. If you then tab to the other textfield... `is_editing` will be false!

The same happens if you replace the above variable assignments with function calls: `enableEditing()` and `disableEditing()`, for example: you tab from one field to another, and editing becomes disabled. That is clearly not what people would want!

To avoid this, most browsers now support `document.activeElement`, which you need to use to do something really nasty like so:

```
function enableEdit() { is_editing = true; }

/* Can't just unset is_editing here, since broken browsers may
call onblur /after/ onfocus when tabbing between two text elements.
So, we only unset if we don't have a text element focused */
function disableEdit() {
  if (!document.activeElement) {
    /* For old & broken browser support, could traverse every DOM elem to set
    elem.onfocus = function(){ document.activeElement = elem; }
    For the meantime, I just assume they aren't broken. */
    is_editing = false;
  }
  // If not focused on a text input type, then it's OK to unset.
  else if ("text" != document.activeElement.type) {
    is_editing = false;
  }
}
```

Obviously, replace the is_editing assignments with whatever you wanted to happen onblur/onfocus.

With jQuery, you can also apparently use `$("*:focus")` in the same way as I used `document.activeElement` above.